# Firebase checking two different database refs despite a if check

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to seperate two different logins for the different types of users that are in the account. One of the users is a regular consumer who is able to search through the app. The other is a business dashboard where businesses get to see what users are checkedin to their business.

The problem is that when I check my two different database references, it seems it checks both of them instead of validating the first check and proceeds to pull and error saying one of my nodes is null.

The case it apprently fails is the first if check but in my database the node userType is set properly:

The problem seems to be it auth().onStateChanged where it looks for the uid of in both database references. When I try to login with a business account it successfully enters that statement and redirects, when I log in with a consumer account it tries to check the business refs if and then pulls out the error `userType is null cannot read`

[image]

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // This prompts the user to allow for location access
      // When logged in it would allow us to show the 
      // nearby businesses to the user 
      var uid = user.uid
      if(window.navigator.geolocation) {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
          
        })
      }

      var uid = user.uid
      console.log(uid)
      business.child(uid).on("value", snap => {
        if(snap.val().userType == "business") {
          alert("This is not a consumer account!")
          firebase.auth().signOut()
          window.location.href = "businesslogin.html"


        } else {
          consumer.child(uid).on("value", snap => {
            if(snap.val().userType == "consumer") {
              if(snap.val().isPhoneVerified == true) {
                window.location.href = 'nearbyBusinesses.html'
              } else {
                window.location.href = 'loginVerification.html'
              }
              if(snap.val().isUserCheckedin == true){
                window.location.href = "leave.html" + '#' + snap.val().checkedInBusinessId
              } else {
                window.location.href = "nearbyBusinesses.html"
              }
            } 
          })
        }
      }) 
  
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you describe exactly what happens when you step through this code (setting breakpoints on the first line of any callback? Which line in that case doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The case of  `if(snap.val().userType == "business)` that line always pulls out an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userType' of null`

Comment: I ended up editing my question with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in this line `if(snap.val() == "business")`. It needs to be `if(snap.val().userType == "business")`. Atleast that is what i can see imediately. Try that and see if it solves your problem

Comment: Sadly that didn't solve the problem. I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userType' of null`

Comment: oh, i forgot.Try this `if(snap.val() && snap.val().userType == "business")`. This will check if the snap actually contains data before trying to access `userType`

Comment: Thanks man it worked can't believe I didn't see that